# Strange behaviour of JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to construct a regex that will match patterns like `H10`, but do not match patterns like `H10=123` (note: instead of H there may be `[A-z]`, instead of 10 - `[0-9]+`)

This one works perfectly on regex101.com:

```
[A-Z]\d+\[^= ](?!=)
```

```
G9=51  // false
H10=10 // false
H10    // true
G0     // true
G0=0   // false
```

But in JS I have the following problem:

```
'G10'.match(/[A-Z]\d+[^= ](?!=)/g) // ['G10']
'G1'.match(/[A-Z]\d+[^= ](?!=)/g) // null
```

The problem is that in JS for a strange reason this regex does not catch patterns with only single number, like G1. Why this can happen if it is a valid regex according to regex101.com?

Comment: It should be `/[A-Z]\d+\b(?!=)/` or `/[A-Z]\d+(?![=\d])/`

Comment: `\d+[^= ]` means one character of something after the digit(s). There is nothing after the digit in "G1".

Comment: BTW, the regex101 yields the same results as your code with `/[A-Z]\d+[^= ](?!=)/`, see https://regex101.com/r/w4ZaNI/2 and https://regex101.com/r/w4ZaNI/3.

Comment: You are tricked by regex101 since you are not testing the regex against multiple strings, but against a single multiline string. Replace `[^= ]` with `[^= \n]`, you will see the difference.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, the second one works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are tricked by regex101 since you are not testing the regex against multiple strings, but against a single multiline string. Replace `[^= ]` with `[^= \n]`, you will see the difference.

You can use

```
/[A-Z]\d+(?![=\d])/
```

*Details*:

- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?![=\d])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `=` or digit char immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6r3MDR/2).